# Material design in API 19 (KitKat)?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

Why the `ListPopupWindow` and the `Dialog` doesn't have material appearance even though I have this in my grade file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1c"
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
```

I tried with different versions of build tools and etc., but without success.
This is how an `AlertDialog` looks like:

[image]

Comment: So where's your code where you create the `AlertDialog`? What is the import you are using for `AlertDialog`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake for the `AlertDialog` I use `import android.app.AlertDialog`

Comment: @ianhanniballake I found where my mistake was.. Thank you bro you helped me alot.

Comment: @Chaos Please post the solution for future readers.

Comment: @frozenkoi I accepted correct answer, hope it will help everyone who had the same problem as mine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html) if you want a consistent `AlertDialog` across all API levels.

Comment: And what about the `ListPopouWinow`'s elevation I can't get that to work..

Comment: @Chaos - that sounds like a different question. Elevation doesn't exist pre-Lollipop

Comment: No.. it is not an attribute to be set.. look at this photo:
http://maogm.com/images/result.png see the border shadow?
in my app there isn't shadow like that..

Comment: Yep, that seems like a new question.

Comment: I have another app with the same gradle and the ListPopopWindow has shadow borders I can't find where the problem is..